# Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean en el ejemplo de Playground Typescript mi solucion usar non-null assertion operator

Tags: typescript

Al ver ejemplos de Typescript en la pagina playground veo que
muestra asignaciones no posibles estas se pueden   obviar usando non-null assertion operator pero cual es el sentido de mostrar ejemplos en esa forma
en la interface definen un tipo posible como undefined y por eso se muestra el error asi tambien ocurre con otros ejemplos de la misma pagina

```
interface Order {
  address: string;
}
interface TelephoneOrder extends Order {
  callerNumber: string;
}
interface InternetOrder extends Order {
  email: string;
}
type PossibleOrders = TelephoneOrder | InternetOrder | undefined;

declare function getOrder(): PossibleOrders;
// error getOrder is not defined debo usar non-null assertion operator
// getOrder()!
const possibleOrder = getOrder();

if ("email" in possibleOrder) {
  const mustBeInternetOrder = possibleOrder;
}
// 'address' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.(2564)
// corrijo con non-null assertion operator address!: string;
class TelephoneOrderClass {
  address: string;
  callerNumber: string;
}

if (possibleOrder instanceof TelephoneOrderClass) {
  const mustBeTelephoneOrder = possibleOrder;
}
if (typeof possibleOrder === "undefined") {
  const definitelyNotAnOder = possibleOrder;
}

// Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
// corrijo con non-null assertion operator  (order && "email")! in roder!
function isAnInternetOrder(order: PossibleOrders): order is InternetOrder {
  return order && "email" in order;
}

function isATelephoneOrder(order: PossibleOrders): order is TelephoneOrder {
  return order && "calledNumber" in order;
}
if (isAnInternetOrder(possibleOrder)) {
  console.log("Order received via email:", possibleOrder.email);
}

if (isATelephoneOrder(possibleOrder)) {
  console.log("Order received via phone:", possibleOrder.callerNumber);
}
```

**  Typescript  pagina playground veo que
muestra asignaciones no posibles se pueden obviar usando non-null assertion operator pero cual es el sentido ?
en la interface definen un tipo posible como undefined esto se repite con otros ejemplos de la misma pagina
**

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: gracias es un problema con código como mencione de la pagina playgroun de la cual puse el link ademas ejemplifique el problema con el código corregido

Comment: debes traer todo al sitio no uses link externos